# How can I change the language of a whole Django CMS website?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I would like to change the language of a website written with the Django CMS from `en-us` to `de` in a way that all present contents in `en-us` will be shown for `de` in the future.

I tried

```
Page.objects.all().update(languages='de')
```

but afterwards there were 404 Errors everywhere.

What else do I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is not compatible with the newer versions of Django CMS. The `language` attribute has been changed into `languages` (also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56162296/522248). For `draft mode` versions of your pages, this contains a comma separated list of available languages. Simply searching for the exact language and updating it to the next version won't work.

Given we want to change 'nl' into 'nl-nl', the following should match:

```
nl,en,de
de,nl,en
en,de,nl
nl
```

We can't just search for 'nl', because the following must not match:

```
nl-nl
nl-nl,en
```

My solution:

```
from_lang = 'nl'
to_lang = 'nl-nl'

# Match our lang at start, middle or end of list
lang_regex = r'^(.*,)?{}(,.*)?$'.format(from_lang)

# Get all distinct combinations of languages that contain our language
language_combinations = Page.objects\
    .filter(languages__regex=lang_regex)\
    .values('languages')\
    .distinct()

# Create a mapping for each combination, replacing the old for the new lang
language_mappings = [
    (
        page['languages'],
        re.sub(lang_regex, '\\1{}\\2'.format(to_lang), page['languages'])
    ) for page in language_combinations
]

# Update all pages to new lang
for old_languages, new_languages in language_mappings:
    Page.objects\
        .filter(languages=old_languages)\
        .update(languages=new_languages)

# Also update Title and CMSPlugins
Title.objects.filter(language=from_lang).update(language=to_lang)
CMSPlugin.objects.filter(language=from_lang).update(language=to_lang)
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the language codes for all content on a django CMS site, run these commands (switching from `'en-us'` to `'de'`:

```py
Page.objects.filter(language='en-us').update('de')
Title.objects.filter(language='en-us').update(language='de')
CMSPlugin.objects.filter(language='en-us').update(language='de')
```

Comment: First I thought fine, but - of course - all cmsplugins are gone now. Can I find a list somewhere that shows all fields I need to change, too? (concerning Placeholders and CMSPlugins)? 

I edited my question to make it clearer that I want to keep the contents.

Comment: You're right, ``CMSPlugin`` also needs updating, I edited my response.

Comment: This answer is no longer applicable to newer versions (3.6.0+) of Django CMS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694763/how-can-i-change-the-language-of-a-whole-django-cms-website/68364150#68364150 that also works on newer versions

Answer (score 1):

To add to @ojii's answer, with django-cms 3.6.0 & django 1.11.20 the procedure now is:

1. Modify `settings.py`:

```py
#LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
```

2. Update Pages, Titles, CMSPlugins (note the `languages` for Pages):

```py
Page.objects.filter(languages='en-us').update(languages='en')
Title.objects.filter(language='en-us').update(language='en')
CMSPlugin.objects.filter(language='en-us').update(language='en')
```